# Open source android VoIP client that does not provide any encryption

Tags: android, voip

Is there any open source android VoIP client that does not provide encryption ?? I need it for my project. I have to encrypt its data.

Comment: Your choice of VOIP client will be dictated in part by your choice of VOIP server. You may be best served by choosing some combination of VOIP client and server where *somebody else* added encryption, so you can follow in that project's footsteps. You can see some work in this area in the OSTN project: https://guardianproject.info/wiki/OSTN

Comment: Thank you. Actually my project is to encrypt VoIP data using AES 128 bit. All the clients I've found are already encrypted.